# Как можно заполнить контейнер для Tab?

Tags: java, android, tab

Хочу сделать tab-s в `NavigationActivity`.И чтоб прокручивать со свайпом.Нашел вот эту либу `it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11` в `README` файле у этого репозитория в `GitHub`-e не увидел как заполнять `Tab`.Подскажите если работали с этой библиотекой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вам какие-то библиотеки, тем более версии 0.11?
Все есть в `Support Library`. Вот эта связка прекрасно работает.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Связываете их между собой вызовом `tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager)`, остальное стандартно по `ViewPager` туториалу.
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral

Comment: Спасибо большое.